# Indicate minimum Blackberry version

Tags: blackberry

How can I indicate the minimum compiled version that I will allow my application to run on? Say OS 5.0 as minimum requirements.

I am using Java with the Eclipse tools.

Answer (score 1):

As Remy says, the minimal supported OS version of your application is determined by the Blackberry SDK version you're using for development.

If you're planning to offer your application through [Blackberry App World](https://appworld.blackberry.com/isvportal/login_input.do?pageId=0), the platform allows you to select the OS Version, carrier and even specific models that are allowed to download your product.

Answer (score 0):

The minimum OS version is dictated by the version of the BlackBerry JRE that you compile with. If you have multiple JRE versions installed, you can select a particular version in the project's properties, in this case the 5.0 JRE.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the minimum OS version you can install your app is determined by the tag `fileset` in your .alx file. Example:

```
<fileset Java="1.54" _blackberryVersion="[4.5.0)">
```

The important info here is the `Java` attribute, the `_blackberryVersion` is only generated by newer plugin versions.

So you can compile a .cod file for let's say 5.0, and install it on 4.5 tweaking that element in the alx file. The alx is only used for BES and cable installs. You can also use JavaLoader and install the cod without caring about OS versions (no alx or jad file needed).

WARNING: The fact that you can install a "wrong" cod on a BlackBerry OS version it is not intended for doesn't mean you can run it without exceptions. If your app uses an API not present in your OS, it will crash.

Of course, the BB plugin generates the correct alx for the selected target OS, but you can bypass it by manually editing the alx if you wish. For OTA installs, the jad file doesn't contain any minimum version info AFAIK, but if it did, you could edit it as well.